# Are any possibilities to post on google+ user's wall (stream) with google+ api?

Tags: google-plus, google-api-php-client

I want to post on google plus user's wall.

I was trying with inserting moments: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert I posted with success but new post(moment) is visible only in application activities.

I was trying to insert googleDomain activity, but there was a lot of problems with scopes and domain restricting. https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert

Now I'm trying to work with Interactive post.

My questions:
- Is possible in this time to post on user's wall (like in fb api)?
- What is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Interactive posts can post directly to the stream, but keep in mind that it will require an explicit user action (ie - they need to click a button on the pop-up to make the post).